# Play framework how to set-up a re-usable comments model

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm wondering if, using play framework 2.0, is it possible to develop a model to handle every comments in site like what I used to do with rails and a GEM like acts_as_commentable_with_threading. Is there, in play, anything like gem systems.

Comment: Play has modules, which are reusable components that you can pull into your projects that add specific functionality. [See here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.1/Modules) for a non exhaustive list of modules. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with a module that provides threaded comments type of functionality. Have you considered using a service like [Disqus](https://disqus.com/)?

Comment: Thaks Donovan. I've already search in those modules. However my question was more generic about the possibility to write plugins that are reusable within any models.